# How to edit a Djano app in production mode in a remote linux server

Tags: python, django, linux, ssh

I have to make changes to a Django application already in production on a linux. Can anyone guide me as to how I can make changes to this application through ssh? I was able to ssh and access the code of the application but I don't know how to commit a change to the application as I don't have access to the runserver terminal like the one I have access to when developing on windows. Also would be helpful if someone could explain how to access the particular python env it's running on. Help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You are able to ssh and access the code of the application, and now want to commit changes to the git repo on the server. Right? Or manually edit?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When running django in production, you will not use the command `python manage.py runserver`. This server is only for development purpose and cannot handle the amount of requests. On your Linux server, you are propably using some WSGI server.

So first you need to find out which combination of WSGI / proxy server is running your django app in production. Then you would upload your app and restart these services. You can read more about the deployment of your django app [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/).

You can check the python version on the server by simply running

```
python --version
```

If there are multiple python environments on the server, you need to check the configuration of the WSGI / proxy you are using to see which python they are accessing.